# How to create a copy of array without modifying it old value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I have two arrays `tasks` and `updatedTasks`. When the first api call is made, one of the properties is updated. When I make a copy of `tasks` array and make a second API to update other property, it adds sadditional properties to `updatedTasks` array. The weird thing is I get the expected result, but both `tasks` and `updatedTasks` have same properties.

Code:

```
const _tasks = []
const _updatedTasks = []
const obj = {
    name: 'task',
  zone: 'zone'
}
const zone = 'abc'
const response = { taskList: [ obj ]};
const response2 = {time: '123'}


response.taskList.map((task)=>{
  task.zone = zone
  const obj = {...task}
  _tasks.push(obj)
})
console.log(_tasks)


const copy = [..._tasks]

copy.map((task)=>{
  const resp = response2
  task.time = resp.time
  _updatedTasks.push(task)
})
console.log(_updatedTasks)
```

How can I make sure, `tasks` just updates `zone` and `updateTasks` updates both `zone` and `time`?

Fiddle Link: https://playcode.io/944175

Comment: This is not Java.

Comment: Doesn't appear to be TypeScript either, since nothing is typed. (Put tags like those in the tag field, not in the title)